# Finding $x$-$t$ function from a complicated $v$-$x$ function

Tags: calculus

Let $v(x)=\sqrt{260x-866.67x^2}$. How to find $x(t)$? Also, let $a(x)=130-866.67x$. How to find $x(t)$?

From the differential equation $v=\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}$ and $\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{v} = \mathrm dt$, I get$$
t = \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{260x-866.67x^2}}.
$$
I think I can get a solution if this integration gets solved but unfortunately I cannot… I have no idea how I can.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compute
$$I=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a x-b x^2}}$$ The first thing is to complete the square
$$-b x^2+ax=-b\left(x-\frac a {2b}\right)^2+b\frac{a^2}{4b^2}=\frac{a^2}{4b}-b\left(x-\frac a {2b}\right)^2$$ So, let $x=y+\frac a{2b}$ to make
$$I=\int \frac {dy}{\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4b}-by^2}}$$ Now manipulate it to get something like
$$I=k\int \frac {dz} {\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$ which must look familiar.